# HTTP with Byte Range with multple Byte range sets

Tags: http, byte, range

I have question on HTTP Server behavior with respect to Byte Ranges.

If client sends a HTTP GET request with multiple byte range sets (i.e 100-200; 300-400 etc.), but HTTP Server is so designed that it only can serve (or parse) first set among these, 
What should HTTP Server do? Does it send a 206 Partial Content only with Content-Range as 100-200/xyz or should it send a 200 OK with the entire file?

Another question is if Client sends a GET with multiple Range headers and each having byte range sets, what is the behavior of the HTTP Server (and especially in the context of above scenario)?

Answer (score 0):

It it can't handle the Range request then it should send the whole resource with a 200 status.

Multiple range headers are invalid, thus 400 would be a correct reply.

Comment: Hi Julian, Thanks for the response.

Comment: For one of the apache servers, I see that two Range headers in a GET is resulting in a 206 Partial content with multipart byte range.

Comment: I am not sure of the exact version of Apache server, but the server header in 206 Partial content says Apache/2